# Mongoose find users with a field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good day everyone!

I have a pretty simple question. Here is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    balance: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },
    clearance: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

All I want is to be able to find all users that HAVE the field. So anyone with ANY clearance would be put on a list, regardless of the actual number. I know how to find users by their id's or their balance, but I don't know how to find users based on just having the field alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

You can use the `$exists` operator

```
User.find({ 
    clearance: { $exists: true } 
}).exec();
```

Keep in mind that this will include documents where clearance is null.

Comment: That should be fine as long as I don't give them a null clearance XD